# Problems with z-index and stacking elements in html

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm creating a navbar as follows.

The main features I want to achieve are:

- Showing a sidebar when clicking the burger button.
- Showing dropdown list when hovering on the menu. The dropdown should be hidden when the pointer leaves the dropdown or the menu.

My problems are:

- The menu list seems to appear in front of the sidebar when it shows. I want the sidebar to be in front of the menu and the green title div, but still behind the topmost navbar (the one with logo). Did I stack them wrong?
- The dropdown doesn't show at all. I once tried do a lot of things until it shows when I hover the menu, but still it appears behind the green title div. Is my element structure still right or should I put the dropdown entirely outside the navbar?

Any help appreciated! :)

```js
$(".burger-btn-wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".main-sidebar").toggleClass("main-sidebar-view");
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 768px; 
}


.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 640px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-top-left {
  z-index: 999;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {
  z-index: 999; 
}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon i {
  font-size: 10px; 
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 32px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:0;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown,
.submenu-dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
} 

.profile-dropdown-check i {
  display: none; 
}

.profile-dropdown-check i.role-active {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #00c983;
}

.main-sidebar {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  left: -260px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  height: 717px;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper {
  height: 669px;
  width: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-sidebar-view {
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
   transition: left 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-section {
  width: 240px; 
}

.sidebar-section li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-section-title {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-icon img {
  width: 18px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar-menu {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-sidebar-footer {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
  
  .callout {
    right: 94px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
  
  .profile-dropdown-icon {
    margin-left: 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">

<div class="navbar">
  
  

<div class="main-sidebar">
  <div class="main-sidebar-list-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Organization</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/LZ44Z0dPvtn2OCGT02lwNZuaUK76Zw69uaYSF4sTe63PtTpKS4IiUM7LjsV5VvlH1hsB6bZM4rA8g9fVsYgUzg/192"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Company</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/8pNCxwrs9k-2fnR6iCzgQ-FEhutp_EcFTTfb9jD207NZSwBU98yuTSPZAKwsh7muBJKKG-MBcsgoqbEpXnZLnQ/213"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Employee</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/mE5M0CywlR63kvqGKenpBEdDFYpOnpHB02javJrGr8r0gJGl_-vuUnKJJpWe6pZChsjIq1yXUgofhicw7MvFCw/177"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Termination</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Compensation &amp; Benefits</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/vYgvWe324-eiGFdWDNoBi7WrWHUAFhEbZCoLWve5NE2rBrFrGmK7ZLjW3W0ggCHce1BCyY6FFTzxRm-Fg9VmBA/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Ketenagakerjaan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/bVKXdl3sBeP8-w1wTrEapdUOlcJFSPi4_koRbRVtzL2NR8N-BPZdJUdpPWjSXC13Um6GLbt5DO1DV2t_j7hQDw/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Kesehatan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/TaVNZzoRbkdvziFtWEyv4sEVQMnVVteQt2CB9aCU4xyOdTaCTDAqL9mqUA-3nGmdJZ7qzLZbxXr2xfXjlVDpDg/173"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Payroll</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/NAZCBsbI_bURxMPsr3N05H2_d8KSiz_RtfaMqHp8Tg8tKFEb4RN-5aHgFQiz0y05Ik4BAD8RMRb5LC-Ufg35zA/175"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">PPh 21</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Admin Panel</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/FNTOwLJTLz1ndzUxgINBH_tCYJgn7rp-HvtVlpTSN1RQ1yuy1q7UskqQikaey0uHl2Fu7C-rXOgaw_VsGH82Lg/136"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">User Management</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/DLaWkbWQ4jxYfEVNpCKBxOyS8G1mzuN24jzbf62tvMsYRvMD0zob2s2K1mBCj62YTYM_MaQmJlt6KmS0WY2uwA/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Master Data</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/h2z5yDkjFcZ5OwhHWcI6VrhUL9Yj-u43QPEjlo7XyHE2pR-ghxrJdXw8mfB5C89AzEd403gqfCrd2JAUMbJ1xQ/199"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Log</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/cn4XSK1tZu9KoSq5Q7iQXAMWcqjw5JolDHCvP52UD2wvu2brkBoit1F7SDUJmFVChGbo1LthZixKzx5ee3jJsQ/156"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Data Migration</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-sidebar-footer">
    &copy; CATAPA 2017
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Employee Directory</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Memo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each"><a href="#">Bulk Update</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download &amp; Upload</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Report</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cover-top"></div>
<div class="cover-left"></div>
<div class="cover-right"></div>
<div class="cover-bottom"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As per your snippet, i am unable to understand your concern, however, i see some problem when i click on the burger menu. If that is the problem just add z-index:1 in your menu-sidebar class

Comment: @satyampathak if I do that, the sidebar will be placed in front of everything. I want the sidebar still behind the first row of the navbar (the one with logo). My other concern is the dropdown from the menu that shown under the green title div

Answer (score 1):

***First of all you should only post relevant code, so that people can find the problem fast.***

Part One:

add this line to the css could help. The probleme is probalby the *precedence*, but honestly there is too much html and css to go through.

```
.main-sidebar.main-sidebar-view{
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Part two:

The dropdown doesn't open probably because there is no javascript that does something, or didn't you paste it?

```js
$(".burger-btn-wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".main-sidebar").toggleClass("main-sidebar-view");
  $(".submenu-dropdown").hide();
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 768px; 
}


.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 640px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-top-left {
  z-index: 999;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {
  z-index: 999; 
}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon i {
  font-size: 10px; 
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 32px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:0;
}

.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown,
.submenu-dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
} 

.profile-dropdown {
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 208px;
  top: 53px;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.profile-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.profile-dropdown-each-section {
  color: #aaa;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.profile-dropdown-check {
  float: right; 
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.profile-dropdown-each-border-top {
  border-top: solid 1px #eee; 
}

.switch-language-group {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.button-language {
  height: 24px;
  width: 32px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-language-left {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}

.button-language-right {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.button-language-active {
  background-color: #00c983; 
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #00c983;
}

.profile-dropdown-check i {
  display: none; 
}

.profile-dropdown-check i.role-active {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-module-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.navbar-module-wrapper:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
}

.navbar-module-wrapper-left {
}

.navbar-module-icon {
  width: 48px; 
  padding: 16px 16px 8px 16px;
}

.caption-basic {
  transform: translateY(8px); 
}

.icon-tm {
  width: 44px; 
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.caption-tm {
  transform: translateY(-8px); 
}

.icon-recr {
  width: 46px; 
}

.caption-recr {
 transform: translateY(4px); 
}

.icon-talent {
  width: 38px;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.caption-talent {
 transform: translateY(-6px); 
}

.icon-bm {
  width: 50px; 
}

.caption-bm {
  transform: translateY(-4px); 
}

.navbar-module-name {
  line-height: 16px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
}

.main-sidebar {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  left: -260px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  height: 717px;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper {
  height: 669px;
  width: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-sidebar-view {
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
   transition: left 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-section {
  width: 240px; 
}

.sidebar-section li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-section-title {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-icon img {
  width: 18px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar-menu {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-sidebar-footer {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
  
  .callout {
    right: 94px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
  
  .profile-dropdown-icon {
    margin-left: 0; 
  }
}

.main-sidebar.main-sidebar-view{
z-index:1000;
background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">

<div class="navbar">
  
  

<div class="main-sidebar">
  <div class="main-sidebar-list-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Organization</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/LZ44Z0dPvtn2OCGT02lwNZuaUK76Zw69uaYSF4sTe63PtTpKS4IiUM7LjsV5VvlH1hsB6bZM4rA8g9fVsYgUzg/192"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Company</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/8pNCxwrs9k-2fnR6iCzgQ-FEhutp_EcFTTfb9jD207NZSwBU98yuTSPZAKwsh7muBJKKG-MBcsgoqbEpXnZLnQ/213"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Employee</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/mE5M0CywlR63kvqGKenpBEdDFYpOnpHB02javJrGr8r0gJGl_-vuUnKJJpWe6pZChsjIq1yXUgofhicw7MvFCw/177"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Termination</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Compensation &amp; Benefits</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/vYgvWe324-eiGFdWDNoBi7WrWHUAFhEbZCoLWve5NE2rBrFrGmK7ZLjW3W0ggCHce1BCyY6FFTzxRm-Fg9VmBA/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Ketenagakerjaan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/bVKXdl3sBeP8-w1wTrEapdUOlcJFSPi4_koRbRVtzL2NR8N-BPZdJUdpPWjSXC13Um6GLbt5DO1DV2t_j7hQDw/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Kesehatan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/TaVNZzoRbkdvziFtWEyv4sEVQMnVVteQt2CB9aCU4xyOdTaCTDAqL9mqUA-3nGmdJZ7qzLZbxXr2xfXjlVDpDg/173"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Payroll</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/NAZCBsbI_bURxMPsr3N05H2_d8KSiz_RtfaMqHp8Tg8tKFEb4RN-5aHgFQiz0y05Ik4BAD8RMRb5LC-Ufg35zA/175"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">PPh 21</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Admin Panel</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/FNTOwLJTLz1ndzUxgINBH_tCYJgn7rp-HvtVlpTSN1RQ1yuy1q7UskqQikaey0uHl2Fu7C-rXOgaw_VsGH82Lg/136"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">User Management</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/DLaWkbWQ4jxYfEVNpCKBxOyS8G1mzuN24jzbf62tvMsYRvMD0zob2s2K1mBCj62YTYM_MaQmJlt6KmS0WY2uwA/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Master Data</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/h2z5yDkjFcZ5OwhHWcI6VrhUL9Yj-u43QPEjlo7XyHE2pR-ghxrJdXw8mfB5C89AzEd403gqfCrd2JAUMbJ1xQ/199"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Log</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/cn4XSK1tZu9KoSq5Q7iQXAMWcqjw5JolDHCvP52UD2wvu2brkBoit1F7SDUJmFVChGbo1LthZixKzx5ee3jJsQ/156"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Data Migration</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-sidebar-footer">
    &copy; CATAPA 2017
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Employee Directory</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Memo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each"><a href="#">Bulk Update</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download &amp; Upload</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Report</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cover-top"></div>
<div class="cover-left"></div>
<div class="cover-right"></div>
<div class="cover-bottom"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1. It would be easy to put the sidebar in front of everything. What I want to achieve is that the sidebar is between the topmost navbar and the menu.
2. this line of css supposed to show the dropdown `.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown,
.submenu-dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}` but it appears behind the green div if you see closely

Comment: That's the problem if you post too much code, and too many questions. It is difficult to find the problem. can you somehow show how it look like in an image or so? for each UseCase?

Comment: i also edited the code to show you my second problem clearly

Answer (score 1):

As per **the first problem** you mentioned in comments, You want that sidebar behind your first row.
Look `z-index` works as per `stack` properties, so the element which is at the top of the stack will serve over others. 
Suppose if `elementA` has a default `z-index:0`  and the other `elementB` you gave `z-index:1` will be on top in the stack and then elementA will be served.

In your case you want `sidebar` behind your first row `nav`.

```
.main-sidebar{
   z-index: -1; // This will lower the stack order compair to zero index elements 
}
```

Have a look at snippet, but sidebar is now behinf everything so you need to position it as per your requirement.

Now this will serve behind every element, unless if any element stack order is lower than that which is `<-1`.

**Your second Problem**
It is not visible or working seems like some js problem or you missed to add some js which makes that hover option enable. Update it i will try to fix it.

```js
$(".burger-btn-wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".main-sidebar").toggleClass("main-sidebar-view");
  $(".submenu-dropdown").hide();
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 768px; 
}
.main-sidebar{
    z-index : -1;
    top : 100%;
 }

.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 640px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-top-left {
  z-index: 999;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {
  z-index: 999; 
}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon i {
  font-size: 10px; 
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 32px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:0;
}

.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown,
.submenu-dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
} 

.profile-dropdown {
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 208px;
  top: 53px;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.profile-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.profile-dropdown-each-section {
  color: #aaa;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.profile-dropdown-check {
  float: right; 
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.profile-dropdown-each-border-top {
  border-top: solid 1px #eee; 
}

.switch-language-group {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.button-language {
  height: 24px;
  width: 32px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-language-left {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}

.button-language-right {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.button-language-active {
  background-color: #00c983; 
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #00c983;
}

.profile-dropdown-check i {
  display: none; 
}

.profile-dropdown-check i.role-active {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-module-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.navbar-module-wrapper:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
}

.navbar-module-wrapper-left {
}

.navbar-module-icon {
  width: 48px; 
  padding: 16px 16px 8px 16px;
}

.caption-basic {
  transform: translateY(8px); 
}

.icon-tm {
  width: 44px; 
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.caption-tm {
  transform: translateY(-8px); 
}

.icon-recr {
  width: 46px; 
}

.caption-recr {
 transform: translateY(4px); 
}

.icon-talent {
  width: 38px;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.caption-talent {
 transform: translateY(-6px); 
}

.icon-bm {
  width: 50px; 
}

.caption-bm {
  transform: translateY(-4px); 
}

.navbar-module-name {
  line-height: 16px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
}

.main-sidebar {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  left: -260px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  height: 717px;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper {
  height: 669px;
  width: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-sidebar-view {
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
   transition: left 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-section {
  width: 240px; 
}

.sidebar-section li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-section-title {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-icon img {
  width: 18px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar-menu {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-sidebar-footer {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
  
  .callout {
    right: 94px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
  
  .profile-dropdown-icon {
    margin-left: 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">

<div class="navbar">
  
  

<div class="main-sidebar">
  <div class="main-sidebar-list-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Organization</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/LZ44Z0dPvtn2OCGT02lwNZuaUK76Zw69uaYSF4sTe63PtTpKS4IiUM7LjsV5VvlH1hsB6bZM4rA8g9fVsYgUzg/192"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Company</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/8pNCxwrs9k-2fnR6iCzgQ-FEhutp_EcFTTfb9jD207NZSwBU98yuTSPZAKwsh7muBJKKG-MBcsgoqbEpXnZLnQ/213"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Employee</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/mE5M0CywlR63kvqGKenpBEdDFYpOnpHB02javJrGr8r0gJGl_-vuUnKJJpWe6pZChsjIq1yXUgofhicw7MvFCw/177"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Termination</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Compensation &amp; Benefits</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/vYgvWe324-eiGFdWDNoBi7WrWHUAFhEbZCoLWve5NE2rBrFrGmK7ZLjW3W0ggCHce1BCyY6FFTzxRm-Fg9VmBA/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Ketenagakerjaan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/bVKXdl3sBeP8-w1wTrEapdUOlcJFSPi4_koRbRVtzL2NR8N-BPZdJUdpPWjSXC13Um6GLbt5DO1DV2t_j7hQDw/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Kesehatan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/TaVNZzoRbkdvziFtWEyv4sEVQMnVVteQt2CB9aCU4xyOdTaCTDAqL9mqUA-3nGmdJZ7qzLZbxXr2xfXjlVDpDg/173"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Payroll</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/NAZCBsbI_bURxMPsr3N05H2_d8KSiz_RtfaMqHp8Tg8tKFEb4RN-5aHgFQiz0y05Ik4BAD8RMRb5LC-Ufg35zA/175"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">PPh 21</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Admin Panel</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/FNTOwLJTLz1ndzUxgINBH_tCYJgn7rp-HvtVlpTSN1RQ1yuy1q7UskqQikaey0uHl2Fu7C-rXOgaw_VsGH82Lg/136"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">User Management</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/DLaWkbWQ4jxYfEVNpCKBxOyS8G1mzuN24jzbf62tvMsYRvMD0zob2s2K1mBCj62YTYM_MaQmJlt6KmS0WY2uwA/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Master Data</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/h2z5yDkjFcZ5OwhHWcI6VrhUL9Yj-u43QPEjlo7XyHE2pR-ghxrJdXw8mfB5C89AzEd403gqfCrd2JAUMbJ1xQ/199"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Log</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/cn4XSK1tZu9KoSq5Q7iQXAMWcqjw5JolDHCvP52UD2wvu2brkBoit1F7SDUJmFVChGbo1LthZixKzx5ee3jJsQ/156"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Data Migration</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-sidebar-footer">
    &copy; CATAPA 2017
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Employee Directory</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Memo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each"><a href="#">Bulk Update</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download &amp; Upload</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Report</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cover-top"></div>
<div class="cover-left"></div>
<div class="cover-right"></div>
<div class="cover-bottom"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1. now the sidebar placed behind everything. 2. this is the line that should do the work `.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown, .submenu-dropdown:hover { display: block; }` but it shows behind the green div. i just edit the code to show you the problem clearly

Comment: yes it is behind the elements whose z-index:0, if you want anyother element behind it just give lower value than -1 to it.

Comment: well it seems like i get what is the problem. It is very interesting that even if i delete the employee list div your hovered menu still not getting visible. i will update once i fix it.

Comment: I don't know why but if I hover the menu *after* I click the burger button it doesn't show anything. If I directly hover the menu after I run the snippet it can clearly shown.. The 1st problem is done tho

Answer (score 1):

I changed:

```
.main-sidebar { z-index: 10; }
.navbar-top { z-index: 11; }
.navbar-logo { z-index: 11; }
```

```js
$(".burger-btn-wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".main-sidebar").toggleClass("main-sidebar-view");
  $(".submenu-dropdown").hide();
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 768px; 
}

.cover-top {
  border-top: solid 12px #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.cover-left {
  border-left: solid 12px #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.cover-right {
  border-right: solid 12px #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -4px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.cover-bottom {
  border-bottom: solid 12px #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 772px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: block; 
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 640px;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 11;
}

.navbar-logo-wrapper img {
  width: 32px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 11;
}

.navbar-top-left {
  z-index: 999;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 16px 0 0;
}

.burger-btn-wrapper i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.module-name {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333;
}

.navbar-top-right {
  z-index: 999; 
}

.navbar-top-middle {
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 0;
}

.modules-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modules-icon i {
  font-size: 16px; 
  color: #333;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.navbar-profile {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profile img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.profpic-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar-profpic {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00c983;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.profile-initial {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.profile-dropdown-icon i {
  font-size: 10px; 
}

.navbar-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-top-middle img {
  height: 32px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar-menu {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.navbar-menu-list {
  width: 750px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu-each {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-menu-each:first-child {
  padding-left: 32px; 
}

.navbar-menu-each a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-on a {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
}

.navbar-page-name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  border-bottom: solid 0.5px #DEF5ED;
  background-color: #F0FBF7;
  color: #333;
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.navbar-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.profile-dropdown {
  background-color: #fff; 
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 106px;
}

.submenu-dropdown {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:0;
}

.navbar-menu-each:hover > .submenu-dropdown,
.submenu-dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 32px 0 24px;
}

.submenu-dropdown-each:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.submenu-selected {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #00c983;
} 

.profile-dropdown {
  padding-top: 8px;
  width: 208px;
  top: 53px;
  right: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.profile-dropdown-each {
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.profile-dropdown-each-section {
  color: #aaa;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.profile-dropdown-check {
  float: right; 
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.profile-dropdown-each-border-top {
  border-top: solid 1px #eee; 
}

.switch-language-group {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.button-language {
  height: 24px;
  width: 32px;
  border: solid 1px #c4c4c4;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-language-left {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}

.button-language-right {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.button-language-active {
  background-color: #00c983; 
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 1px #00c983;
}

.profile-dropdown-check i {
  display: none; 
}

.profile-dropdown-check i.role-active {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #00c983;
}

.callout {
  width: 260px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 25px;
  min-height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  position: absolute;
  right: 102px;
  top: 32px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}

.callout::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.callout.bottom::before {
  left: 45%;
  top: -20px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f8f8f8;
}

.callout-title {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  padding-left: 16px;
}

.callout-content {
  display: block;
  padding: 16px;
}

.callout-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-module-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.navbar-module-wrapper:hover {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
}

.navbar-module-wrapper-left {
}

.navbar-module-icon {
  width: 48px; 
  padding: 16px 16px 8px 16px;
}

.caption-basic {
  transform: translateY(8px); 
}

.icon-tm {
  width: 44px; 
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

.caption-tm {
  transform: translateY(-8px); 
}

.icon-recr {
  width: 46px; 
}

.caption-recr {
 transform: translateY(4px); 
}

.icon-talent {
  width: 38px;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.caption-talent {
 transform: translateY(-6px); 
}

.icon-bm {
  width: 50px; 
}

.caption-bm {
  transform: translateY(-4px); 
}

.navbar-module-name {
  line-height: 16px; 
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 60px;
}

.main-sidebar {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  width: 240px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 51px;
  left: -260px;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
  transition: left 0.5s;
  height: 717px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper {
  height: 669px;
  width: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.main-sidebar-view {
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transition: left 0.5s;
   transition: left 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-section {
  width: 240px; 
}

.sidebar-section li {
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-section-title {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 28px;
  height: 48px;
}

.sidebar-icon img {
  width: 18px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar-menu {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: top;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}

.main-sidebar-list-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.main-sidebar-footer {
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: solid 1px #eee;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 24px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 24px;
  }
  
  .callout {
    right: 94px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .module-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .profile-name {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .modules-icon {
    display: none; 
  }
  
  .navbar-top {
    padding: 0 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-menu-each:first-child {
    padding-left: 16px; 
  }
  
  .navbar-page-name {
    padding-left: 16px;
  }
  
  .profile-dropdown-icon {
    margin-left: 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">

<div class="navbar">
  
  

<div class="main-sidebar">
  <div class="main-sidebar-list-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Organization</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/LZ44Z0dPvtn2OCGT02lwNZuaUK76Zw69uaYSF4sTe63PtTpKS4IiUM7LjsV5VvlH1hsB6bZM4rA8g9fVsYgUzg/192"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Company</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/8pNCxwrs9k-2fnR6iCzgQ-FEhutp_EcFTTfb9jD207NZSwBU98yuTSPZAKwsh7muBJKKG-MBcsgoqbEpXnZLnQ/213"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Employee</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/mE5M0CywlR63kvqGKenpBEdDFYpOnpHB02javJrGr8r0gJGl_-vuUnKJJpWe6pZChsjIq1yXUgofhicw7MvFCw/177"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Termination</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Compensation &amp; Benefits</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/YlkzS0yo52ARysEUFWYs53WfQH7D1kGaAoxmnqhpSOX7nDKTgYxPsF8CuP-EQlJBNM_ye68YqYc2J0BcSLPJwg/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Setup</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/vYgvWe324-eiGFdWDNoBi7WrWHUAFhEbZCoLWve5NE2rBrFrGmK7ZLjW3W0ggCHce1BCyY6FFTzxRm-Fg9VmBA/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Ketenagakerjaan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/bVKXdl3sBeP8-w1wTrEapdUOlcJFSPi4_koRbRVtzL2NR8N-BPZdJUdpPWjSXC13Um6GLbt5DO1DV2t_j7hQDw/168"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">BPJS Kesehatan</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/TaVNZzoRbkdvziFtWEyv4sEVQMnVVteQt2CB9aCU4xyOdTaCTDAqL9mqUA-3nGmdJZ7qzLZbxXr2xfXjlVDpDg/173"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Payroll</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/NAZCBsbI_bURxMPsr3N05H2_d8KSiz_RtfaMqHp8Tg8tKFEb4RN-5aHgFQiz0y05Ik4BAD8RMRb5LC-Ufg35zA/175"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">PPh 21</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sidebar-section">
    <li class="sidebar-section-title">Admin Panel</li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/FNTOwLJTLz1ndzUxgINBH_tCYJgn7rp-HvtVlpTSN1RQ1yuy1q7UskqQikaey0uHl2Fu7C-rXOgaw_VsGH82Lg/136"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">User Management</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/DLaWkbWQ4jxYfEVNpCKBxOyS8G1mzuN24jzbf62tvMsYRvMD0zob2s2K1mBCj62YTYM_MaQmJlt6KmS0WY2uwA/159"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Master Data</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/h2z5yDkjFcZ5OwhHWcI6VrhUL9Yj-u43QPEjlo7XyHE2pR-ghxrJdXw8mfB5C89AzEd403gqfCrd2JAUMbJ1xQ/199"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Log</span>
    </li>
    <li class="sidebar-section-each">
      <span class="sidebar-icon"><img src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/cn4XSK1tZu9KoSq5Q7iQXAMWcqjw5JolDHCvP52UD2wvu2brkBoit1F7SDUJmFVChGbo1LthZixKzx5ee3jJsQ/156"></span>
      <span class="sidebar-menu">Data Migration</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-sidebar-footer">
    &copy; CATAPA 2017
  </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="navbar-logo-wrapper">
    <img class="navbar-tree" src="https://cdn.frontify.com/api/screen/thumbnail/7UV_lfX5OBfHxFn5lc3ygK8UTU3z5pivwY9QDSDIOiFemj-DdmDzmwiPvbibaG63IMXz-MmGOs4aH-UqgoT9gw/350">
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-top">
    <div class="navbar-top-left">
      <div class="burger-btn-wrapper">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="module-name">Employee</div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-top-right">
      <div class="modules-icon"><i class="fas fa-th"></i></div>
      <div class="navbar-profile">
        <div class="profpic-wrapper">
          <div class="navbar-profpic">
            <div class="profile-initial">DJ</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-name">Dennis Jonathan</div>
        <div class="profile-dropdown-icon"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-menu">
    <ul class="navbar-menu-list">
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Employee Directory</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>New Employee Registration</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each submenu-selected'>Employee List</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Rehire</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without Bank Account</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Without PPh 21</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Memo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Memo Template</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Print Memo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each"><a href="#">Bulk Update</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Download &amp; Upload</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Send Email</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Approvals and Undo</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Approvals</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employment Status Undo</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar-menu-each">
        <a href="#">Report</a>
        <ul class="submenu-dropdown">
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Data Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Headcount Report</li>
          <li class='submenu-dropdown-each'>Employee Recapitulation Report</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-page-name">
    Employee List
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cover-top"></div>
<div class="cover-left"></div>
<div class="cover-right"></div>
<div class="cover-bottom"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is *almost* the answer, thank you! Another problem is can you try hovering my menu on the snippet (without clicking the burger button before)? As you can see the dropdown is behind the green bar. Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you sure? I select the words perfectly.